# With the HttpRequestData in Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http, how does one retrieve the Remote IP address?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

With an Azure Function App written in .NET 3.x, an HTTP Trigger binding gives you access to an `HttpRequest` object. e.g.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
```

From that you could inspect `'{req.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}'` to log out where the request is coming from.

With the .NET 5 isolated worker model, the HTTP Trigger binding gives you an [HTTPRequestData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httprequestdata?view=azure-dotnet) object. e.g.

```
public static HttpResponseData Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
```

Is this Remote IP information available still? Is it on the `FunctionContext` or `Headers` property?